# integrating wordpress with apache

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

i have installed apache 2.2, php5, mysql separately and as far as they are concerned apache, mysql ans php are working fine with each other, the problem arises when i place the wordpress (unzip) in my htdocs folder the ur; "http://localhost:81/wordpress" works fine but returs the kind of result as shown in the picture i have uploaded ... hw can i resolve this...[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting DirectoryIndex (http://bignosebird.com/apache/a2.shtml) within *httpd.conf* or *.htaccess*

```
DirectoryIndex ..., index.php
```

You can also try to set the correct Handler via

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Comment: tnx Tobiask it worked like a charm... but now when i type localhost:81/ instead of showing It Works! it gives me a dir listing... just out of curiosity :)